# Export looped layers at once using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, buffer, qgis-processing, loop

I am trying to use one-side buffer on road centerline (layer name: small_road) by 1~40m. I've succeeded in creating one buffer (2m) file at a time using

```
'SEGMENTS':2,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/sky/Desktop/1/buffer/b1.shp'})
```

Then how can I save multiple buffer files at once using loop? I've tried below code for loop, but it only creates one file named 'x.shp' with 40m buffer.

```
for x in range (41):
    processing.run("qgis:singlesidedbuffer", {'INPUT':'small_road','DISTANCE':x,'SIDE':0,'SEGMENTS':2,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/sky/Desktop/1/buffer/x.shp'})
```

I also tried changing the output name into `'OUTPUT':'"C:/Path/Buffer" + str(x) + ".shp"'` but it gives me error (core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is because you are combining two different quotation marks (double " and single ') in your name outfile. I tried out your code (with my paths and only two layers in the loop) as follows and it worked.

```
import processing

layer = iface.activeLayer()

for i in range(2):

    processing.run("qgis:singlesidedbuffer", 
                   {'INPUT':layer,
                   'DISTANCE':2,
                   'SIDE':0,
                   'SEGMENTS':2,
                   'JOIN_STYLE':0,
                   'MITER_LIMIT':2,
                   'OUTPUT': '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/b' + str(i+1) + '.shp'})
```

Comment: I would recommend using `format`. Like `'/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/b{}.shp'.format(i+1)`

Comment: thank you so much! it's working now :)

Comment: I’m happy to help.